# Unity Dash shows up while drag-n-dropping a selection in GTK apps

Tags: unity, gtk, unity-dash

If the Unity Dash is hidden (using app maximized) I make a selection in a GTK app and I drag-n-drop it, the Unity Dash shows up. I'm not sure it's a feature or a bug, but sometimes it stays there and doesn't wanna disappear. The only way I could manage to hide it was to move a selection behind it and back.

It behaved so when I tried it with Chrome, Firefox and Nautilus, and it didn't with MySQL Workbench and Netbeans IDE.

EDIT: Actually I managed to stick the dash also with Netbeans, had to move a tab.

EDIT2: Filed the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/777203

Comment: Think it qualifies as a bug. I've made a few such papercut bug reports myself, they are important. Bug reports go here https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity

Comment: Yeah this is bug territory, here's more instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug